# Why is this use of strcpy considered bad?

Tags: c, buffer, strcpy

I've spotted the following piece of **C** code, marked as BAD (aka buffer overflow bad).
The problem is I don't quite get why? The input string length is captured before the allocation etc.

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *c = malloc(len);
    if (c) {
        strcpy(c, s);  // BAD
    }
    return c;
}
```

Update from comments:

- the 'BAD' marker is not precise, the code is not bad, not efficient yes, risky (below) yes,
- why risky? `+1` after the strlen() call is *required* to safely allocate the space on heap that also will keep the string terminator (`'\0'`)

Comment: looks ok to me, assuming `s` is a well-formed C string .. ?

Comment: If that's okay, could you maybe provide the source / document which labeled this snippet as unsafe. From what I'm seeing this is perfectly safe code.

Comment: @yano You cannot determin if a string is well-formed. The only check that is missing here is a check against `NULL` to determin whether the pointer you received is "valid".

Comment: @DiegoROJAS This function should _not_ check for NULL, it should crash on NULL. ([Explanation](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563).)

Comment: I suspect the author of the "BAD" remark simply didn't see the `+ 1`.  It's a common enough mistake to omit that +1, and a casual reader could easily overlook it.  It might be clearer to write the code as `len = strlen(s); char *c = malloc(len + 1);`.  Personally, I take the overallocation and like to write `malloc(len + sizeof '\0')`

Comment: @WilliamPursell You are aware that the type of `'\0'` is `int`, yes?

Comment: @zwol I would assume as much since he specifically wrote "overallocation"

Comment: Of course, @zwol, I discourage the author of the question from implementing such checks as they are indeed harmful.

Comment: I suppose one could also write `malloc(len + sizeof '\0' - (sizeof(int) - 1))`, but that seems less readable. ;)

Comment: it look very similar to `strdup()`

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Use `sizeof ""`, as in `malloc(len + sizeof "");`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no bug in your sample function.

However, to make it *obvious* to future readers (both human and mechanical) that there is no bug, you should replace the `strcpy` call with a `memcpy`:

```
char *my_strdup(const char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s) + 1;
    char *c = malloc(len);
    if (c) {
        memcpy(c, s, len);
    }
    return c;
}
```

Either way, `len` bytes are allocated and `len` bytes are copied, but with `memcpy` that fact stands out much more clearly to the reader.

Comment: do you advocate not using string functions?

Comment: `memcpy` also doesn't waste time looking for `\0` in the original string so `memcpy` has the potential of being cheaper than using `strcpy`.

Comment: @yano I am for or against specific string functions on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: legitimately asking, what's a case for using `strcpy` if not here? I like @TedLyngmo 's point about speed. Historically I've used string functions for strings, `memcpy` for everything else, maybe I should rethink that.

Comment: @zwol IMO memcpy suggests that the s is not the string (which contradicts the strlen). Less clear. OF course memcpy will be more efficient.

Comment: I think `memcpy` makes it clearer to the reader. There is no doubt that there are `len` chars that we can copy. Personally I would have to look at the code twice as long if I noticed `strcpy` there. "_Why?_" I would think. "_Has anything happened since we just counted above?_" - Only after reading it an extra time would I be sure that there is nothing fishy going on.

Comment: @yano I think what I would say about `strcpy` specifically is that I have yet to encounter a situation where correct code that uses strcpy could not be made clearer by switching to some other function (often, but not always, either memcpy or snprintf).

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with this code.

While it's possible that `strcpy` can cause [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) if the destination buffer isn't large enough to hold the string in question, the buffer is allocated to be the correct size.  This means there is no risk of overrunning the buffer.

You may see some guides recommend using `strncpy` instead, which allows you to specify the maximum number of characters to copy, but this has its own problems.  If the source string is too long, only the specified number of characters will be copied, however this also means that the string isn't null terminated which requires the user to do so manually.  For example:

```
char src[] = "test data";
char dest[5];

strncpy(dest, src, sizeof dest);  // dest holds "test " with no null terminator
dest[sizeof(dest) - 1] = 0;       // manually null terminate, dest holds "test"
```

I tend towards the use of `strcpy` if I know the source string will fit, otherwise I'll use `strncpy` and manually null-terminate.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see any problem with the code when it comes to the use of `strcpy`

But you should be aware that it requires `s` to be a valid C string. That is a reasonable requirement, but it should be specified.

If you want, you could put in a simple check for NULL, but I would say that it's ok to do without it. If you're about to make a copy of a "string" pointed to by a null pointer, then you probably should check either the argument or the result. But if you want, just add this as the first line:

```
if(!s) return NULL;
```

But as I said, it does not add much. It just makes it possible to change

```
if(!str) {
    // Handle error
} else {
    new_str = my_strdup(str);
}
```

to:

```
new_str = my_strdup(str);
if(!new_str) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Not really a huge gain